# If statements end always to the first statement

Tags: powershell

I have following script that check our service prinpical in our Azure AD and check what state are the client secret

```
Write-Host 'Gathering necessary information...'
$applications = Get-AzADApplication
$servicePrincipals = Get-AzADServicePrincipal

$appWithCredentials = @()
$appWithCredentials += $applications | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | ForEach-Object {
    $application = $_
    $sp = $servicePrincipals | Where-Object ApplicationId -eq $application.ApplicationId
    Write-Verbose ('Fetching information for application {0}' -f $application.DisplayName)
    $application | Get-AzADAppCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = { $application.DisplayName } }, @{Name = 'ObjectId'; Expression = { $application.Id } }, @{Name = 'ApplicationId'; Expression = { $application.ApplicationId } }, @{Name = 'KeyId'; Expression = { $_.KeyId } }, @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = { $_.Type } }, @{Name = 'StartDate'; Expression = { $_.StartDate -as [datetime] } }, @{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime } }
}

Write-Host 'Validating expiration data...'
$today = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$limitDate = $today.AddDays(30)
$appWithCredentials | Sort-Object EndDate | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.EndDateTime -lt $today) {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'Expired'
    }
    elseif ($_.EndDateTime -le $limitDate) {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'ExpiringSoon'
    }
    else {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Status' -Value 'Valid'
    }
}
```

So, all secrets go to state'Expired' even though it not even near

[image]

Here are the current formats

```
$_.EndDateTime = 20.10.2022 9.29.56

$today = Thursday 27. October 2022 10.51.05
```

I have now tried all what I can or think of so could any of you spot the mistake that I'm making?

Comment: Well, you are using `elseif`, so that remaining checks won't be performed when the first `if` is fulfilled.

Comment: Make sure `$_.EndDateTime` is an actual date and not a string that looks like a date. It's not being casted to datetime, unlike the `StartDate` is.

Comment: If `$_.EndDateTime` doesn't convert to a valid `DateTime` type in your current culture when you use the [\[DateTime\]::TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tryparse(system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-datetime@)) method, you can use a regex `-replace` operation to convert to a string `TryParse()` can recognize...

Comment: Are you sure `@{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime } }` should not be `@{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDate} }` ?? Perhaps [Get-AzADAppCredential EndDate and StartDate strings in different format](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/16506) can help?

Comment: @Theo They have changes EndDate to EndDateTime.

Comment: Seems almost that $_.EndDateTime would not really print anything in my ForEach-Object thus everything goes to Expired state..

Comment: Did you try the link I added to my comment?

Comment: Yes I tried. They have changed that so that Get-Date matched with Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $AppObjectId  and (Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $AppObjectId | select PasswordCredentials).PasswordCredentials.EndDateTime. They have also changed EndDate to EndDateTime.  I would say that my issue is on the row that starts with $application | Get-AzADAppCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object and were EndDate is following: @{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime -as [datetime] } }. This somehow chaging the time format.